# how to upload a file with variable name

Tags: php

I have a problem with uploading file,
 I am Using this code......
and getting this error,

my folder name is garment_images

```
 <?php
    $pid          = mysql_insert_id();
    $folder       = $_post['catagory'];
    //insert images into folder
    $product_name = "$pid.jpg";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['productImage']['tmp_name'], "$folder._images" / $product_name);
    echo "<h1>Your product successfully added <br /> Plese wait....</h1>";
    header("refresh:3; url='inventory.php'");
    exit();
    ?>
    <form method='post' action='index.php'>
    <input type="file" name="productImage" />
<input type="text" name="catagory" />
    </form>
```

Comment: what problem ... ? I think you have several spelling mistakes too. (catagory -> category, refreash -> refresh)

Comment: 1) use space after `<?php`; 2) use `$_POST` instead of $_post; 3) `"$table._images"` will be (if $table = 'table' ) `'table._images'` 4) string / string will be bool(false) with warning *Division by zero* (in this case) 5) the header is named `Refresh`, not `refreash`, besides use instead `Location`.

Answer (score 2):

Several mistakes corrected, here is your code:

```
<?php
$pid          = mysql_insert_id();
$folder       = $_POST['category']; // assuming you had category other wise, no correction
//insert images into folder
$product_name = "$pid.jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['productImage']['tmp_name'], "$table._images/ $product_name"); // string concat mistake
echo "<h1>Your product successfully added <br /> Please wait....</h1>";
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3; inventory.php' />";// use meta tag to redirect instead of header which will give you headers already sent error
// exit(); // if not commented out, the below form will never be shown!
?>
<form method='post' action='index.php'>
<input type="file" name="productImage" />
</form>
```

I strongly suggest you use an IDE while coding if you are getting started with PHP, and need help with it.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote 'refreash', correct is 'refresh'.